# R: sparse matrix (simple_triplet_matrix - TextDocumentMatrix) to big to be processed with apply

Tags: r, bigdata, text-mining, tm

I have TextDocumentMatrix `tdm` (terms: 66779, documents: 609551, Non-sparse entries: 9704315). I'm trying to process it with pieces of code listed below:

```
# 1. counting sum of term values for each document
colTotals = apply(tdm , 2, sum)

# 2. Singular Value Decomposition 
s = svd(as.matrix(tdm), nu = nrow(tdm), nv = ncol(tdm))

# 3. Latent Semantic Analysis (with lsa package)
sp = lsa(tdm)
```

Each of the calls listed above (1, 2, 3) causes an error:

```
Error in vector(typeof(x$v), nr * nc) : vector size cannot be NA
In addition: Warning message:
In nr * nc : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

How can I process so big matrix?

Comment: Which call throws the error message?  Have you tried dividing the tdm in half, for example, to see whether R can handle the smaller object?

Comment: I've updated the question a little. Each of these calls causes the error. When I decrease the number of terms (e.g. by removal of terms that occur in less than 1/1000 of documents, instead of 1/100000) to ~2700 it works fine.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28259464/1036500 for an explanation